# Use a variable twice in prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm beginning to use prepared statements with my sql queries in php and in starting with this I have come up with a question.

I have a function that grabs a user's id from a table at login.  I want the user to be able to use either their username or email address for their login.

So my sql statement is:

> SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `username`=? OR `emailAddress`=?

Now essentially when in this query `username` and `emailAddress` will be the same because it can be either or.

So when binding my statements do I bind my variable twice:

```
bind_param('ss', $user, $user);
```

So the value for `username` and `emailAddress` needs to be the same.  Essentially I want `$user` to be the value of both the placeholders.

My questions are:  **Am I doing this correctly?**  **Is there a more efficient way?**

Comment: Have you tried it?  Does that work?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you want to know if it works? Then please try it, and if it doesn't, update your question with any error messages.

Comment: @victorantunes I guess what I should have asked is: Is there a better way to do this?  Is this the correct way?

Comment: I +1'd this as I have a _similar_ issue except that I'm not populating the bind parameters from code (where I agree, it's trivial to just include it twice or more), but from within a clunky GUI where additional "slots" need to be created and then populated for each bind in the query.  So being able to eg reference each bind as ?1, ?2, ?3, and then use ?2 in more than one location, would actually be a time saver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you would have to bind it twice.  If you are opposed to that for some reason, you could rephrase the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `login` l cross join
      (select ? as thename) const
WHERE l.`username` = thename OR `emailAddress` = thename;
```

This is using a subquery to name the parameter so it can be referred to multiple times in the query.

Comment: @EvanStoddard I hope you won't use this twisted query only to save a bound parameter, would you?

Comment: Don't know what that means.  I'm just trying to prevent injection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There have to be as many variables in the `bind_param()` call as there are placeholders in the query. Consider if you had:

```
SELECT * FROM login
WHERE username = ? and emailAddress = ? and country = ?
```

and you tried to bind too few of them:

```
bind_param("ss", $user, $country);
```

How is it supposed to know which variable should be repeated for the extra placeholder?

There's no problem with using the same variable twice. I wouldn't recommend it with bind_result, though -- it will presumably allow it, but I don't know if it's predictable which column will be put into the variable.

Comment: I am using `OR` though.  The fact is, when the user logs in, you don't know whether they will use their email address or username.  So the value needs to be the same for each placeholder.  So I guess what I should have asked is: what's a better way to do this?