# MYSql prepare not accepting my request: No tables used

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using MySQLi in php to prevent SQL Injection with my table.

I have the following SQL command that works perfectly if input into phpMyAdmin.

```
INSERT INTO UsageData (MyID) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'USER') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT MyID FROM UsageData WHERE MyID = 'USER') LIMIT 1
```

Essentially it is intended to insert a new row with MyID as 'USER' if such a row does not already exist.

I have tried to do this with php like so

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO UsageData (MyID) SELECT * FROM (SELECT ?) AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT MyID FROM UsageData WHERE MyID = ? ) LIMIT 1";
if ($statement1 = $database->prepare($query1)) {
    $statement1->bind_param("ss", $inID, $inID);
    $statement1->execute();
    $statement1->close();
} else {
    echo "Incorrect SQL 1\n";
    echo "Query: ".$query1."\n";
    echo $database->error."\n";
}
```

However this always results in the echoing of "Incorrect SQL". The error mentioned is "No tables used".

I have a SQL request sent right after it in the PHP that works perfectly but this one for some reason does not.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Just to be clear, the two parameters you have in your SQL are both meant to be the same input? So you're not just missing one?

Comment: Correct both of the places should be the same variable $myId

Comment: You could try binding the ID twice, once for each location it is used in the SQL statement. Apparently the number of variables needs to match the number of bound parameters. Link to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600368/use-a-variable-twice-in-prepared-statement

Comment: @Steve I am not sure what the insight is supposed to be from that post. It looks like the code was working fine for him and he was just wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to assume that you've done the work to properly set up the database handler by doing something like `$database = new pdo(...);`

I'm a little foggy as to what happens when you put assignment statements inside the as an if condition. I would advise you to do the assignment before the `if-else` block  and then test to see `if ($statement1 === false)` (testing for equivalence, not just equality) for an error. Otherwise, you can enclose `$database->prepare(...)` in a `try-catch` block as it emits a PDOException if something goes wrong like this:

```
try {
    $statement1 = $database->prepare($query1);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("PDO Exception: " . $e->getCode() . ": " . $e->getMessage());
}
```