# Where in the MySQL doc could I find an explanation of const

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am trying to understand the syntax and usage of the keyword `const` in MySQL. I can't find any information about it in the official MySQL docs. Where could I find an explanation of its usage? I am interested only in official explanation, not third party tutorials, but if such documentation does not exist, could someone explain to me how `const` works?

e.g. `const` in this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `login` l cross join
      (select ? as thename) const
WHERE l.`username` = thename OR `emailAddress` = thename;
```

Comment: Const is an alias not a keyword. Search for sql alias

Comment: @P.Salmon I think you are right. This would explain why I couldn't find it in the documentation. FYI I got this from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600368/use-a-variable-twice-in-prepared-statement/18600992#18600992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL standard defines multiple ways of phrasing subqueries. One of them is called "table expression" (aka "inline view").

The case you are talking about is a simple table expressions in the form:

```
SELECT * FROM (<subquery>) <alias> WHERE <condition>
```

In your case `const` is the alias.